# Returning a nested object with Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am creating an application with several interconnected items. One of the things I would like to do, is easily fetch nested objects based on relationships. Say I have the json structure displayed below:

```
Categories = [
{
   name: "projectors",
   productTypes: [
   {
       name: "panasonic",
       products: [
          {
           id: "d.1.1",
           model: "PT-DZ680"
          },
          {
           id: "d.1.2",
           model: "PT-DZ680"
          }]       
   }]
}]
```

I have so far created nodes for both categories, productTypes and products. And i've created a relationship between categories->productTypes and productTypes->products.

Based on the example given in [Nested has_many relationships in cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682024/nested-has-many-relationships-in-cypher) , i've formulated the following code.

```
var categoriesWithProducts = Client.Cypher
                    .Match(
                        "(category:Category) -[:ISUNDERCATEGORY]->(productType:ProductType)-[:ISTYPEOF]->(product:Product)")
                    .With((category, productType, product) => new
                    {
                        category,
                        productType,
                        products = product.CollectAs<Product>()
                    })
                    .With((category, productType, products) => new
                    {
                        category,
                        productTypes = "collect({Name: productType.Name, Products:products})"
                    })
                    .Return((category, productTypes) => new
                    {
                        Name = category.As<Category>().Name,
                        ProductTypes = productTypes.As<ProductType>()
                    })
                    .Results;
```

This is the closest I've come to returning the structure above. And it currently results in the following error:

> Neo4j returned a valid response, however Neo4jClient was unable to
>   deserialize into the object structure you supplied.
>
> First, try and review the exception below to work out what broke.
>
> If it's not obvious, you can ask for help at
>
> Include the full text of this exception, including this message, the
>   stack trace, and all of the inner exception details.
>
> Include the full type definition of
>   <>f__AnonymousType3`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[Proddler.Frontend.Models.ProductType,
>   Proddler.Frontend, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]].
>
> Include this raw JSON, with any sensitive values replaced with
>   non-sensitive equivalents:
>
> {   "columns" : [ "Name", "ProductTypes" ],   "data" : [ [ "Skærme", [
>   {
>       "Name" : "Panasonic",
>       "Products" : [ {
>         "labels" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/labels",
>         "outgoing_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/relationships/out",
>         "data" : {
>           "Name" : "super awesomeSkærm",
>           "Guid" : "28a16c87-135a-4afe-9bef-8470e1ece860",
>           "Id" : "d.1.7"
>         },
>         "traverse" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/traverse/{returnType}",
>         "all_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
>         "self" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15",
>         "property" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/properties/{key}",
>         "properties" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/properties",
>         "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
>         "incoming_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/relationships/in",
>         "extensions" : {
>         },
>         "create_relationship" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/relationships",
>         "paged_traverse" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
>         "all_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/relationships/all",
>         "incoming_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/15/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
>       }, {
>         "labels" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/labels",
>         "outgoing_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/relationships/out",
>         "data" : {
>           "Name" : "super awesomeSkærm2",
>           "Guid" : "a3191f2e-2974-4d1b-a7cf-65200677e36c",
>           "Id" : "d.1.7"
>         },
>         "traverse" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/traverse/{returnType}",
>         "all_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
>         "self" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16",
>         "property" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/properties/{key}",
>         "properties" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/properties",
>         "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
>         "incoming_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/relationships/in",
>         "extensions" : {
>         },
>         "create_relationship" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/relationships",
>         "paged_traverse" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
>         "all_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/relationships/all",
>         "incoming_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/16/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
>       }, {
>         "labels" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/labels",
>         "outgoing_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/relationships/out",
>         "data" : {
>           "Name" : "super awesomeSkærm2",
>           "Guid" : "a3191f2e-2974-4d1b-a7cf-65200677e36c",
>           "Id" : "d.1.7"
>         },
>         "traverse" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/traverse/{returnType}",
>         "all_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
>         "self" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17",
>         "property" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/properties/{key}",
>         "properties" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/properties",
>         "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
>         "incoming_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/relationships/in",
>         "extensions" : {
>         },
>         "create_relationship" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/relationships",
>         "paged_traverse" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
>         "all_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/relationships/all",
>         "incoming_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/17/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
>       } ]   },  {
>         "labels" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/labels",
>         "outgoing_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/relationships/out",
>         "data" : {
>           "Name" : "Sony Bravia 2",
>           "Guid" : "ad4263d4-7647-46e0-a53c-a6b232c47457",
>           "Id" : "d.1.8"
>         },
>         "traverse" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/traverse/{returnType}",
>         "all_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
>         "self" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22",
>         "property" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/properties/{key}",
>         "properties" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/properties",
>         "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
>         "incoming_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/relationships/in",
>         "extensions" : {
>         },
>         "create_relationship" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/relationships",
>         "paged_traverse" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
>         "all_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/relationships/all",
>         "incoming_typed_relationships" : "....net:7474/db/data/node/22/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}"
>       } ]   } ] ] ] } Parameter name: content

First of all, I have now idea whether my approach is correct. Secondly, I have no clue how to resolve the error I am now facing.

I apologize if my question is trivial!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar stuggle at the moment. Did you get this working?

Comment: Same issue as you're facing with