# Represent infinite depth nodes in nested json form in neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I have graph with each node having Parent relationship with its child (as shown in attached image) and a name attribute . [image] I want to display this graph in the from of nested json object like this:

```
{name: A,
 children: [{name: A1,
           children: A11, A12, A13 },

            {name: A2,
            children: A21, A22, A23},

            {name: A3,
             children: A31, A32, A33}
           ]}
```

I want to traverse any depth so the rlationship should be sort of (a)-[*]->(b).
With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682024/nested-has-many-relationships-in-cypher%22this%20question%22), I came up with following query:

```
match(parent{name: "A"})-[*]->(child)
with parent, child, collect(child.name) as children
return {name: parent.name,
    children: collect({name: child.name,
                      children: children})}
```

But the above query produces following result:

```
    name    A
    children    [
    name    A23
    children    [A23]
    ,
    name    A22
    children    [A22]
    ,
    name    A32
    children    [A32]
    ,
    name    A2
    children    [A2]
    ,
    name    A12
    children    [A12]
    ,
    name    A21
    children    [A21]
    ,
    name    A31
    children    [A31]
    ,
    name    A1
    children    [A1]
    ,
    name    A11
    children    [A11]
    ,
    name    A33
    children    [A33]
    ,
    name    A3
    children    [A3]
    ,
    name    A13
    children    [A13]
    ]
```

So, what could be the possible solution to represent this full tree in the form of json object as mentioned above?

Comment: Can you please attach the sample output if it is giving some

Comment: Done. just edited my question and shared output of the query!

Comment: I dont know the exact solution but match(parent{name: "A"})-[*]->(child) matches all the nodes connected to A as child of A. You wont get the immediate parent of that child.

Comment: yes. Is there a way we can store or do processing on intermediate parents like fetching A1 and then storing its children using collect?

Comment: how about before starting for infinite depth you start with finite known depth and try something like match(parent{name: "A"})-[:Parent*]->(child)-[:Parent*1]->(grandchild) and then collect the results according to your requirement. (Not sure if it will work though)

Answer (score 3):

I added a function like this to APOC, feel free to check it out:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#fromtojson

```
CREATE p1=(m:Movie {title:'M'})<-[:ACTED_IN {role:'R1'}]-(:Actor {name:'A1'}), 
 p2 = (m)<-[:ACTED_IN  {role:'R2'}]-(:Actor {name:'A2'}) WITH [p1,p2] as paths 
 CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) YIELD value RETURN value
->
{_id=0, _type=Movie, title=M, 
 acted_in=[
   {_id=1, _type=Actor, name=A1, acted_in.role=R1}, 
   {_id=2, _type=Actor, name=A2, acted_in.role=R2}]}
```